# Can somone please explain this to me

Tags: c, pointers

For `n=3` and `a={1,2,3},b={4,5,6}` its supposed to calculate `1*4+2*5+3*6`.
I don't understand why does it work because p is a pointer and `p=produs(a,b,n)` means that the address of p becomes the value returned by produs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void citire(int *x,int *n)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=*n; i++)
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
}

int produs(int *a,int*b,int n)
{
    int produs=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        produs=a[i]*b[i]+produs;
    return produs;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int*p;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int *a=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    int *b=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    citire(a,&n);
    citire(b,&n);
    p=produs(a,b,n);
    printf("%d",p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays in C start with 0, not 1, so your loop `for(int i=1; i<=*n; i++)` leaves the first element in the array alone, and accesses one item past the end of the array.

Comment: Although you have declared `p` as a pointer, you aren't really using it as one. Because your `produs` function returns an `int`, then that value will be assigned to p (pointers are, after all, *integral* types). If you later tried to use it as a pointer, you would get *undefined behaviour* as it wont be pointing at anything meaningful.

Comment: When asking questions use the title to communicate the observable problem. "Not understanding" is too broad. Not understanding what, specifically?

Comment: Did your compiler show some warnings to you?

Comment: "Why does it work" is not very useful. Do you think, it should behave different? Do you expect it to crash? If a program contains *undefined behaviour*, it is still a perfectly valid behaviour to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
size_t size = 10;
int* x = calloc(size, sizeof(int));
```

You get an array `x` with 10 items in it, indexed 0..9, not 1..10. Here [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) is used to make it abundantly clear what's being requested instead of doing multiplication that can be mysterious or obtuse.

As such, to iterate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  x[i] ...
}
```

You have a number of off-by-one errors in your code due to assuming arrays are 1..N and not 0..(N-1).

Putting it all together and cleaning up your code yields:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void citire(int *x, size_t s)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < s; i++)
            scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    }

    int produs(int *a, int* b, size_t s)
    {
        int produs = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
            produs = a[i] * b[i] + produs;

        return produs;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);

        int* a = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        int* b = calloc(n, sizeof(int));

        citire(a, n);
        citire(b, n);

        // produs() returns int, not int*
        int p = produs(a,b,n);
        printf("%d", p);

        return 0;
    }
```

You're using pointers in places where pointers don't belong. In C passing a pointer to a single value means "this is mutable", but you don't change those values, so no pointer is necessary nor advised.

Try and use `size_t` as the "size of thing" type. That's what's used throughout C and it's an unsigned value as negative indexes or array lengths don't make any sense.